# Why does this C++ program take so long to finish if you run it as a root?

Tags: c++, caching

I want to clear L1, L2 and L3 cache 50 times by executing the following code. However it becomes very slow if I run it by typing `sudo ./a.out`. On the other hand, if I just write `./a.out` it will finish executing almost instantly. I do not understand the reason for this since I am not getting any errors in the terminal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

void clear_cache(){
    sync();
    std::ofstream ofs("/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches");
    ofs << "3" << std::endl;
    sync();
}


int main() {

    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        clear_cache();

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Define "very slow". Maybe the sudo version actually sets it, and the other just ignores your requests. This seems like an odd thing to do in the first place. What's your goal here?

Comment: ~10 seconds if you run it as a root.

Comment: Does `sudo` anything else take a minimum of ten seconds? How long does this operation take to complete via shell? You can usually check using the `time` command.

Comment: No, only for this program

Comment: This clears the kernel caches, not the CPU caches. I'm not sure if there's a way to do that from userland, but you certainly don't want to do this. ([Here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cachetlb.txt) is how to do it from the kernel).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't have enough permissions to write to this file as a regular user:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Feb 11 15:56 /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Only version run as a privileged user works, hence it takes longer. The reason you're not getting any errors is that you're not checking any errors.

Here's the most simple check:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

void clear_cache(){
    sync();
    std::ofstream ofs("/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches");

    if (!ofs)
    {
        std::cout << "could not open file" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ofs << "3" << std::endl;
    sync();
}


int main() {

    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        clear_cache();

    return 0;
};
```

Output:

```
% ./a.out    
could not open file
```